# last() in spawned functions

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

Why would the `fn:last()` function not work while spawning?

This failed:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $items := (1, 2, 3)
return xdmp:spawn-function(function () {
   $items[3 to fn:last()] 
})
```

After some time I cancel the job because it does nothing.

> **Output:** Cancelling fails with message indication function must be stopped manually.

This works just fine:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $items := (1, 2, 3)[3 to fn:last()] 
return xdmp:spawn-function(function () {
   $items
})
```

> **Output:** Query completed successfully

Comment: "Failed" is not really a reasonable problem description. How did it fail, is there an error message?

Comment: The first returns an XDMP-MEMORY at my end. I think it is worth filing a bug at MarkLogic Support. Need help with that?

Comment: In that case I will report it. Thanks.

Comment: when I ran this in QConsole, they both did the same thing... "your query returned an empty sequence". Where are you running this code?

Comment: @StuBob: Ran this in MarkLogic 8.04 on windows and on a separate MarkLogic 8-0.3 centos install.

Comment: @chriskelly I was running on ML7... interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example for the docs of [`fn:last()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/fn:last) is showing a very similar usage of this function. The downside for using functions in predicates is though that they are evaluated for each item in the sequence. Using [`fn:subsequence`](http://docs.marklogic.com/fn:subsequence) and optionally [`fn:count`](http://docs.marklogic.com/fn:count) should both be more efficient, and by-pass your issue:

```
let $items := (1, 2, 3)
return xdmp:spawn-function(function () {
   xdmp:log(subsequence($items, 3, count($items))) (: you can omit 3rd param with same effect :)
})
```

HTH!

Comment: This solves my problem for sure. I'll report it anyway though since it's unexpected behavior. Thanks!